# How can I delete a URL rewrite rule in IIS7 from the command prompt if it's got spaces in the name?

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, appcmd

The appcmd help is a little vague and I can't seem to figure out the proper escape or quoting sequence.

> appcmd set config
>   -section:defaultDocument /-files.[value='main.html']
>
> Remove a collection element with
>   the specified keys in the 
>   collection of the
>   "system.webServer/defaultDocument"
>   configuration    section.

This works fine:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /-[name='rulename']
```

This does not:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /-[name='rule name']
```

The rule in question has multiple spaces and a forward slash (/) in the name.

Comment: Did you try "rule%20name"? I don't know if it will work but I would try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to delete using a combination of double and single quotes like:

appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /-"[name='test rule with / in name']"

Try using Configuration Editor, it will generate the AppCmd.exe command automatically, it is included in IIS 7.5 and you can download it for IIS 7.0 at http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack